# Laravel middleware Auth work in controller but not in my middleware

Tags: laravel, authentication, middleware

i'm in trouble for 2 days with the laravel auth middlewares.

I have understand how the Auth system work with JWTtoken. In my controller all work fine i got my user login and i can access with Auth::guard->user().

But i have one problem in my middleware Authenticate.php :

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authenticate as Middleware;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

use Closure;

class Authenticate extends Middleware
{

    protected function redirectTo($request)
    {   dd(
            $request->user(),
            auth()->id() ?? '?',
            Auth::id() ?? '?',
            $request->user()->id ?? '?',
            auth()->check(),
            get_class(auth()->guard())
        );
    }

}
```

I try everything i found in multiple post or tutorial, but the result is the same (same time in controller all work user is login) :

```
null
"?"
"?"
"?"
false
"Tymon\JWTAuth\JWTGuard"
```

AuthController.php

```
public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth', ['except' => ['login', 'register']]);
    }

public function login(Request $request){
    $credentials = $request->only('email', 'password');

    if(!$token = $this->guard()->attempt($credentials)){
        return response()->json(['error' => "L'email ou le mot de passe ne correspondent pas."]);
    }else {
        return response()->json([
            'token' => $token,
        ]);
    }
}
public function guard()
{
    return Auth::guard();
}

And Multiple function me,logout...
```

Kernel.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Http;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel as HttpKernel;

class Kernel extends HttpKernel
{
    protected $middleware = [
        // \App\Http\Middleware\TrustHosts::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\TrustProxies::class,
        \Fruitcake\Cors\HandleCors::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\CheckForMaintenanceMode::class,
        \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\ValidatePostSize::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\TrimStrings::class,
        \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\ConvertEmptyStringsToNull::class,
    ];

    protected $middlewareGroups = [
        'web' => [
            \App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
            \Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse::class,
            \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
            // \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\AuthenticateSession::class,
            \Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
            \App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,
            \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
        ],

        'api' => [
            //'throttle:60,1',
            \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
        ],
    ];

    protected $routeMiddleware = [
        'auth' => \App\Http\Middleware\Authenticate::class,
        'auth.basic' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\AuthenticateWithBasicAuth::class,
        'bindings' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
        'cache.headers' => \Illuminate\Http\Middleware\SetCacheHeaders::class,
        'can' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authorize::class,
        'guest' => \App\Http\Middleware\RedirectIfAuthenticated::class,
        'password.confirm' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\RequirePassword::class,
        'signed' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ValidateSignature::class,
        'throttle' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ThrottleRequests::class,
        'verified' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\EnsureEmailIsVerified::class,
    ];

}
```

I have try to take rules in $middlewareGroups web and past in $middleware, and if i do that is say :
"Call to a member function parameters() on null".

So nothing change my Auth is null.

Thanks a lot if someone can explain me the problem and what i do wrong !

EDIT :

api.php

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'auth', 'namespace' => 'Auth'], function ($router) {
    Route::post('/inscription', 'AuthController@register');
    Route::post('/connexion', 'AuthController@login');
    Route::get('/logout', 'AuthController@logout');
    Route::get('/me', 'AuthController@me');
    Route::get('/isAdmin', 'AuthController@isAdmin');
});
```

Solution not found :(

Comment: add your route file .. did you use  it ?

Comment: Yes, i didn't add because my route work fine all my function in my controller work too.

Comment: please add route file also... it is not possible to explain by comment...

Comment: You did not use Auth; on the top...

Comment: I have add api.php route file in bottom of the post.
You talk to other file ??

Comment: Sorry for this...

Comment: Np, when you say no use Auth. You talk in api.php ? Because the namespace is string so nothing change if i had then.

Comment: add in middleware `use Auth`...after `use Closure;`

Comment: I try before (and retry) but norhing change and i learn the "Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;" is equal path to "Auth".

Comment: you did not use middleware .. use it in route file  like `Route::group(['prefix' => 'auth', 'namespace' => 'Auth' , 'middleware' => 'auth:web'],`

Comment: what happen now ? problem solve ?

Comment: It's not change, i use it in controller i like more that way. But is the same result unfortunately :/ (if i had :web my logic is broke and i don't get Auth in controller)

Comment: i did not see any more errors in your code.... what error are you getting now ? maybe problem with other code ..

Comment: I don't have a real error. The problem is in same time in front i got my user with Auth::guard()->user() by controller but in middleware is null . For me the problem is something execute after middleware maybe at this time in middleware the Auth is null. But no really found where ...

Comment: do you want check user role ?

Comment: No i just want check if user login

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/222070/discussion-between-abdullah-al-noor-and-raphael-rollet).

Comment: auth middleware check user is login or not ...  it's laravel default facility ..

Comment: I don't solve my problem if someone as other idea please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Authenticate.php

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next, ...$guards)
{
    $this->authenticate($request, $guards);

    $user = $this->auth->user();

    ...do your thing....
```

Kernel.php

```
protected $middlewareGroups = [
    'api' => [
        \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
        \AEPlanning\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,
```

You will get user only after successful login